# Is “add fourteen days and subtract two years to and from the current datetime” correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, parallelism

I have the following sentence:

> We add fourteen days and subtract two years **to and from** the current datetime.

I am not sure about the *to and from* part.

How can this sentence be rephrased if not correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative way, also difficult to follow, is:

> We add fourteen days **to** and subtract two years **from** the current datetime.

---

To transmit the information clearly, the following is the best:

> We add fourteen days to the current datetime. Then we subtract two years.

The message is extremely easy to get.

Comment: And is the sentence grammar correct?

Comment: I am not sure. I think that your sentence is incorrect because you take the prepositions away from their place and group them together. A native speaker might clarify this for us.

Comment: Virolino is right. The original sentence merely confuses. His suggestions resolve the problem.

Comment: The original sentence is grammatical but ugly and confusing.  Virolino's suggestions are good solutions.